# Load an ArcGIS Vector Tiled Layer from a URL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-tiles, vector-layer, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

.net core 3.1 Wpf application use Esri.ArcGISRuntime.WPF v100.7.0., tries to view vector tile from own tile server, but nothing displays.

my code:

```
ArcGISVectorTiledLayer vectorTiledLayer = new ArcGISVectorTiledLayer(uri);
var basemap = new Basemap(vectorTiledLayer);
Map map = new Map(basemap);
MapView.Map = map;
```

Similar code on javascript works fine.
Can you help me?

Comment: For what it's worth, the code looks fine, so probably an issue with the URL?
Try calling `await vectorTiledLayer.LoadAsync()` and see if an error is thrown, and if so what error